# Conditions for Weak and Strong law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, definition, statistical-inference, law-of-large-numbers

I am a second-year undergraduate student and was reading up the topics of the law of large numbers from *Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference*. They state the laws as follows:

[The link to the Statements of the laws as per the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUgQJ.png)

Here, As per the statements, if the same assumptions on the random variable are satisfied (The R.Vs being IIDs and EX to be finite), Then Both the laws do hold true. The book does go on to state that the condition of finite variance is not a necessary one.

It is here that I have 2 Doubts:

1. To what extent are the conditions accurate for either the WLLN or SLLN to be true, when stated here in the book? I somehow find it slightly difficult to believe that only the condition EX is finite can cause the laws to be valid in all possible (maybe even pathological) distributions and scenarios.
2. If both the Laws have the same sufficiency conditions, then how is it possible that in some cases, the WLLN may hold and the SLLN doesn't? I tried reading the *Wikipedia* page on [Law of Large Numbers](https:///en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law), but couldn't make sense of the examples given there with respect to what quality causes them to satisfy WLLN but not SLLN.

I hope you do see my Dilemma here. Thanks

Comment: There are conditions, namely the variance is also finite and the variables are iid.

Comment: As for 2) you are misinterpreting. The two statements (strong and weak law) have the same hypothesis so they are both true when the hypothesis are satisfied. The weak law is simpler to prove that's why it is presented.

Comment: @lcv I agree that as they have the same hypotheses, they both should be true together. However, I have seen in many claims in lectures, SE questions and sources that there exist examples where WLLN holds but SLLN doesn't. I want to understand how it can be so.

Comment: The weak law can hold not surprisingly under more general conditions than the strong law.

Comment: @lcv I do probably see your point, though I'll have to look up the general conditions. But Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the only required condition for i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ to have a sample average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ that converges to $E[X_1]$  prob 1 (and hence in probability) is that the mean $E[X_1]$ is finite (and in fact only pairwise independence is required, rather than mutual independence). This was proven in a famous paper by Etemadi ("An elementary proof of the strong law of large numbers" 1981).   But the case of finite variance is easier to prove, and as lcv points out, converence in probability is easier to prove than convergence with prob 1.